# Java Code for AI Game

Tags: java, arrays, artificial-intelligence, chess

I am currently in the process of developing a Java game which is similiar to checkers.

There are two players, `player X` and `player Y`. I do not want a GUI for this game, just an output below. In the game, player `X` starts at `[0,0]` and player `Y` starts at `[7,7]`.

My first problem is I am not sure how to enter i.e `[3,6]`, to get player `X` to move to `[3,6]`.

When player `X` moves from `[0,0]`, then `[0,0]` should be marked as unavailable, therefore, neither player can either go to that space or jump over it and this is my second problem as I am not sure how this can be done.

The aim of the game is really to get one of the players in a position of not being able to move anywhere. We are meant to add different AI's into it but if I get the basis working I can try develop the AI's.

I am not the strongest programmer therefore if my code can be edited in anyway to make things easier, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

My code is as follows:

```
public static AIProject {

    public static String [][] board = new String[9][9];

    public static void addPiece(int x, int y, String r) {
        board [x][y] = r;
    }

    public static void showBoard() {
        for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("-------------------");

            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print("I");
                if(board[col][row] == null) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(board[col][row]);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
    }   

    public static void mainn(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(board.length);

        addPiece(0,0,"0");
        addPiece(0,1,"1");
        addPiece(0,2,"2");
        addPiece(0,3,"3");
        addPiece(0,4,"4");
        addPiece(0,5,"5");
        addPiece(0,6,"6");
        addPiece(0,7,"7");
        addPiece(0,8,"8");
        addPiece(1,0,"1");
        addPiece(2,0,"2");
        addPiece(3,0,"3");
        addPiece(4,0,"4");
        addPiece(5,0,"5");
        addPiece(6,0,"6");
        addPiece(7,0,"7");
        addPiece(8,0,"8");

        addPiece(1,1,"X");
        addPiece(8,8,"Y");

        showBoard();
     }
}
```

Comment: So you question is basically how to interact with a user?

Comment: Ye pretty much, I just need be able to input a space on the board to x or y to move to and whatever space x or y moved from, mark that as unavailable or mark it as * so x or y can't move there or jump over it

Comment: If you are coding a checkers AI, the biggest problem you'll have is finding an AI algorithm. For checkers, [minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) could do. It's well known and it's teached in many AI courses, but it will let you down when the search space gets big. For games like "go", have a look at [Monte Carlo Tree Search](http://mcts.ai/about/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

> My first problem is I am not sure how to enter i.e [3,6], to get player X to move to [3,6].

You can use some meaningfull coordinates - for example if user wants to go to [3,6] then one enters 36 etc. The labels for coordinates should be visible on board.

> When player X moves from [0,0], then [0,0] should be marked as unavailable, therefore, neither player can either go to that space or jump over it and this is my second problem as I am not sure how this can be done.

You can create new class, for instance BoardItem - it will contain isOccupied and label fields - label would show player label if the field would be occupied or the coordinates it the field is not occupied.

I also recommend to count the arrays from 1, not from 0. It will be more meaningfull for the user - "when I want to go to 1 row, 1 column I have to enter 11".

My proposed solution:

```
public static AIProject {

private static int BOARD_SIZE = 8;

static BoardItem[][] board = new BoardItem[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];

// available players
public static String[] players = { "X", "Y" };

// x,y are the coordinates, label is the string, it can take coordinates or
// player name if the field is occupied
public static void addPiece(int x, int y, String label, boolean isOccupied)    {
// here we are assigning to a specific board piece a BoardItem - label      and if it
// is occupied
    board[x][y] = new BoardItem(label, isOccupied);
}

public static void showBoard() {
    for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_SIZE; col++) {
            if (board[col][row] == null) {
                System.out.print("\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print(board[col][row] + "\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n_____________________________________________________________");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // board creating
    for (int x = 1; x < BOARD_SIZE ; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < BOARD_SIZE ; y++) {
          // as you can see in method definition we are passing coordinates 
         // as integers in 2 first arguments, next coordinates as string
         // this "label" would be displayed on board
         // the last parameter is indicating that the field are not occupied
            addPiece(x, y, x + "" + y, false);
        }
    }
    // however, you want to point that 1,1 is occupied by player 'X'...
    addPiece(1, 1, players[0], true);
    // and 7,7 is occupied by player 'Y'
    addPiece(7, 7, players[1], true);

    // 'X' is active player now
    String activePlayer = players[0];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // infinite loop - in the loop condition you should check
    // if someone lose/win to end the game
    while (true) {
        // clearing output
        clearScreen();
        // showing board            
        showBoard();
        // moving player - waiting for input from player and then 
        // mark chosen coordinates as occupied by active player
        playerMove(activePlayer, keyboard);
        // changing active player. First X, then Y, then X and so on.
        activePlayer = changeActivePlayer(activePlayer);
    }

}

private static void playerMove(String player, Scanner keyboard) {

    BoardItem boardItem = getBoardItemForPosition(keyboard.next());
    // it should be isNotValid
    while (boardItem.isOccupied()) {
        System.out.println("Chosen position is occupied! Please choose another one");
        boardItem = getBoardItemForPosition(keyboard.next());
    }
    boardItem.setOccupied(true);
    boardItem.setLabel(player);
}

private static BoardItem getBoardItemForPosition(String position) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(position.substring(0, 1));
    int y = Integer.parseInt(position.substring(1, 2));
    return board[x][y];
}

private static String changeActivePlayer(String activePlayer) {
    if (activePlayer.equals(players[0])) {
        return players[1];
    }
    return players[0];
}

private static void clearScreen() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        System.out.println();
}
}
```

And the BoardItem class:

```
public class BoardItem {

private String label;

private boolean isOccupied;

public BoardItem(String label, boolean isOccupied) {
    this.label = label;
    this.isOccupied = isOccupied;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public boolean isOccupied() {
    return isOccupied;
}

public void setOccupied(boolean isOccupied) {
    this.isOccupied = isOccupied;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return label;
}

}
```

Another tips:

- class with main method should only start the application, whole logic should be elsewhere;
- you should write a validation for user input and check there if the user enters correct input - 2 numbers in appropiate range, if the field is occupied or not and if user could move to the specified field;
- I would change all arrays to new classes, but thats only a suggestion :) one class should be responsible for 1 thing: for starting the application, for creating and priting the view, for player movement with appropiate validation.

Comment: Thank you for that, Although, when trying to move X, I type 1167 to move x from 1,1 to 6,7. But it says space is occupied but this is my first move. How do I start off them all blank except 1,1(where x starts) and 7,7(where y starts). And once I make that move, I make 1,1 occupied too as thats where I have just moved from? Thanks for your help

Comment: For the version I've pasted, you only have to type the destination e.g. "67" - 2 first letters of the input are 'x' and 'y'. They are set as non occupied, only 1,1 and 7,7 are they are set here:
addPiece(1, 1, players[0], true);
addPiece(7, 7, players[1], true); Do you want me to comment the code?

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks. Yes if you can that would be great. Thanks for the help